# Start node.js server with subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, node.js, subprocess, popen

I have a `node.js` server (abbreviated here). The `/healthcheck` endpoint is regularly pinged

```
        var app = express();

        app.get('/healthcheck', function(req, res) {
            promiseTimeout(getPing(transId), TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS)
            .then(() => {
                // success health
                logger.info("healthy");
                res.status(200).send()
            })
            .catch(() => {
            // broken health
                logger.info("unhealthy");
                res.status(500).send();
            })

        });

        app.use(function(req, res) {
            res.status(404).send("Sorry, that route doesn't exist.");
        });

        var server = app.listen(PORT, function () {
            logger.info("http server app listening on port %s", PORT);
        });
```

It is started by a python script which is abbreviated here

```
def handler():
        # Handle SIGTERM here    

def start_web_server():
        print "starting web server"
        # start web server
        proc = subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/nodejs", "/usr/src/app/http_server.js"], shell=False)

        return proc

def start():
        proc = start_web_server()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)
        start()
```

Now after `proc = start_web_server()` I want to do something else, for example verifying endpoints. The solution I know is to use `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `subprocess.call()`.

However, once I do this, the `/healthcheck` endpoint will fail after awhile. It looks like `call` is blocking so the server is kept up but `Popen` is non-blocking so the server is somehow shutdown. My intuition is that `Popen` should not close the subprocess by itself.

What is the cause of this? And what is the solution for my problem i.e. do something after starting the `node.js` server?

**EDIT 1:** the /healthcheck fails due to connection deny.